# CollapseToolbarLayout with TabbarLayout

Tags: android, material-design

How to make something like it

[image]

My solution is so close to ideal, but have some problems. Tabs dissaper with image. How to fix it? Tabs in "expanded mobe" must be with image on background! Thanks for your answer!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="56dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="nothing to show"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/empty"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifications :

- just remove `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` from `TabLayout`
- Change `android:gravity="bottom"` to `android:gravity="top"` in `Toolbar`.

  ```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/coordinator"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

      <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
          android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
          app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/header_image"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:scaleType="centerCrop"
              app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:gravity="top"
              app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
              app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

          <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
              android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
              app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
              app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
              app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>

      </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay"
      app:behavior_overlapTop="56dp"/>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:text="nothing to show"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:id="@+id/empty"/>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
  ```

**Edit1:** You have to provide add a specific `height` to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Removed `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from `TextView`.

You can also checkout this [Sample](https://github.com/vitovalov/TabbedCoordinatorLayout/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) for more information.

Comment: see the edited code.

Comment: thanks! It's not bad. But not allow implement "overlap" in RecyclerVIew